kafka-acls.sh Command Fails with Operations Containing Underscores in Kafka 2.7.0
I’m experiencing issues when setting ACLs for my users in Kafka 2.7.0. Specifically, the kafka-acls.sh command fails when using operations that contain underscores. However, similar commands for operations without underscores seem to work correctly.
Here’s an example of a working command with an operation without an underscore:
kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --deny-principal User:kafkaConsole --cluster --operation ALTER

Adding ACLs for resource `ResourcePattern(resourceType=CLUSTER, name=kafka-cluster, patternType=LITERAL)`:
    (principal=User:kafkaConsole, host=*, operation=ALTER, permissionType=DENY) 

Current ACLs for resource `ResourcePattern(resourceType=CLUSTER, name=kafka-cluster, patternType=LITERAL)`:
    (principal=User:kafkaConsole, host=*, operation=ALTER, permissionType=DENY)


kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --deny-principal User:kafkaConsole --cluster --operation ALTER_CONFIGS


ResourceType TOPIC only supports operations ALTER_CONFIGS, DESCRIBE_CONFIGS, DESCRIBE, WRITE, ALL, DELETE, CREATE, ALTER, READ


I tried to set ACLs using the kafka-acls.sh command for both operations with and without underscores. For operations without underscores (e.g., ALTER), the command executed successfully and the ACL was correctly applied. However, for operations with underscores (e.g., ALTER_CONFIGS), the command failed with an error indicating that the operation is not supported. I expected the command to work similarly for both types of operations, as ALTER_CONFIGS is listed as a valid operation in the documentation.

if we just use two part commands without underscore like ALTERCONFIG or other operations without their underscore it will work correctly.

The --cluster flag in Kafka is used to apply ACLs at the cluster level, which controls access to administrative operations on the entire Kafka cluster, such as creating or deleting topics and managing ACLs.
Operations like ALTER_CONFIGS are not valid at the cluster level, as they are specifically for configuring topics, not for the cluster itself.
The error happens because the ALTER_CONFIGS operation is specific to topics and brokers, not the Kafka cluster. When you apply ACLs at the cluster level, only certain operations are supported (e.g., ALTER, DESCRIBE, etc.), and ALTER_CONFIGS isn't one of them.
Solution:
If you want to deny the ALTER_CONFIGS permission for a topic, you should target a specific topic instead of the cluster.
For example, to apply the ALTER_CONFIGS operation on a topic named my-topic, modify the command like this:
kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 \
  --add --deny-principal User:kafkaConsole \
  --topic my-topic --operation ALTER_CONFIGS



i think it's valid command because when i try it without underscore it works correctly and allow or deny changing cluster config.
